# Building help system for a sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a sharepoint webapp that contains multiple site collections. Different users have rights to different subset of those site collections. I need to create a help system for that web application. For each of the site collections there will be several documents and/or videos that describe how to use that site collection. The requirement is that users should only have access to the help documents corresponding to the site collections they have rights for.

What is the best way to create and orgranize that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a document library in each site collection to store the help files. Then you can make sure people who have permission to see the site also get permission to view that document library in each site collection.

Comment: what if I wanted to have links to all help docs on the same page, filtered by what site collections the user can see?

Comment: You could do that with a custom query, it will likely be easier to just have a link to the document library on each site collection